# How to add rangeslider.js for controlling drag of Slick Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, slick.js, rangeslider

I am trying to combine range slider with slick slider for drag functionality but I'm stuck with integrating it, tried manupulate the offset but slick slider resets after it changes slide again.

Here is what i have been able to do so far

```
    $(function(){

        function getSlides(){
            var slidetrack = $(".slick-track");
            var width = slidetrack[0].clientWidth;
            var slides = $(".slick-slide").length;
            var min = width/slides;
            var max = width;

            //console.log(width);
            //console.log(slides + "|" + min + "|" + max);
            var input = '<input type="range" min="'+ min +'" max="'+ max +'" value="0" step="1" data-rangeslider>';
            $(".budget").append(input);
            ranger(slidetrack,min);
        }

        function ranger(slidetrack,min){
            $('input[type="range"]').rangeslider({
                polyfill:false,
                onInit:function(){
                },
                onSlide:function(position, value){
                    slidetrack.css("left",min-value+"px");
                },
                onSlideEnd:function(position, value){
                    //console.log('onSlideEnd');
                    //console.log('position: ' + position, 'value: ' + value);
                }
            });
        }

        function slickIt(){
            $(".single-item").slick({
                centerMode: true,
              slidesToShow: 3,
              infinite:false
            });
        }
        slickIt();
        getSlides();

    });
```

Codepen : https://codepen.io/mjn/pen/NzdpGG

Comment: You are actually changing the CSS `left` attribute of an element on which there is a plugin instance (Slick). That seems to works, but the plugin doesn't know about that change. I suggest you fully examine the [toolset Slick has to offer](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) about **events** and **methods** to programmatically detect/change the current slide. You'll have some maths to do about the rangeslider position (in percentage) to match a slide number. I would look for the `slickGoTo` method. -- Good luck!

Comment: @Louys actually the slickGoto method i can work with but i need drag effect not just slide.. i mean slide along with knob

Comment: hello @Manjunath Did you find a solution? I'm trying to achieve the exact same effect, but I cannot seem to make it work. I was hoping you could help me out here.

Comment: @HuubS Unfortunately I did not. I gave up the idea as due to some reasons but i'll add to my checklist to achieve it when i get time :)

Comment: @Manjunath Thanks for the reply. I will go with the other option that is changing the slide when it reaches a certain treshold. Dragging seems to be impossible, except maybe changing the x coordinate of the transform.

Answer (score 0):

make the following change and try it will be starting from the first slide before you move the slider.
        function slickIt(){
            $(".single-item").slick({
                centerMode: false,
...

Let me know whether It got what you are looking for...

Comment: It's not what i was looking for. I need knob to control slider.